# Adding array as HashTable value

Tags: json, powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script which passes a JSON to a C# module.

The following is the JSON:

```json
{
"Header":  {
               "Message":  {
                               "EDept":  [
                                              "Computers",
                                              "Electronics", 
                                              "Electricals"
                                          ],
                               "EId":  "001",
                               "Emp":  "All"
                           },
               "AnotherArray":  [
                                    "E1",
                                    "E2",
                                    "E3"
                                ],
               "ID":  "JOPP"
           }
}
```

I basically have two Arrays/List which are : "EDept" & "AnotherArray".
AnotherArray is fine but EDept is not taken as an array !!

This is PSScript:

```bsh
$Header = @{}
$Header.Add("ID", "JOPP")

$message = @{}
$message.Add("Emp", "All")
$message.Add("EId", "001")
$EDept = @("Computers", "Electronics", "Electricals")
$message.Add("EDept", $EDept)
$Header.Add("Message", $message)

$anotherArray = @("E1", "E2", "E3")
$Header.Add("AnotherArray", $anotherArray)

$main= @{}
$main.Add("Header", $Header)

$mainjson = $main | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output ($mainjson)
```

but the output that I get is:

```json
{
    "Header":  {
                   "Message":  {
                                   "EDept":  "Computers Electronics     Electricals",
                                   "EId":  "001",
                                   "Emp":  "All"
                               },
                   "AnotherArray":  [
                                        "E1",
                                        "E2",
                                        "E3"
                                    ],
                   "ID":  "JOPP"
               }
}
```

If you see here my `AnotherArray` is fine but "EDept" is taken a single string rather than a array. I am defing both in the same way.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple fix.  Use the `-depth` parameter in your call to `ConvertTo-Json`:

```
$mainjson = $main| ConvertTo-Json -depth 99

Write-Output ($mainjson )
{
    "Header":  {
                   "Message":  {
                                   "EDept":  [
                                                 "Computers",
                                                 "Electronics",
                                                 "Electricals"
                                             ],
                                   "EId":  "001",
                                   "Emp":  "All"
                               },
                   "AnotherArray":  [
                                        "E1",
                                        "E2",
                                        "E3"
                                    ],
                   "ID":  "JOPP"
               }
}
```

This has bitten me *many* times, and is one of the few things in PowerShell that I believe they got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`ConvertTo-Json` has [`Depth` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json#-depth) that specifies, how many level of contained objects will be included in result JSON. In your case, it's enough to add `-Depth 3` and you'll get expected result.

Alternatively you can use [Newtonsoft.Json module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json/1.0.1.2), which has `ConvertFrom-JsonNewtonsoft` and `ConvertTo-JsonNewtonsoft` cmdlets that are wrappers for [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).